# TextMate: Added custom syntax highlighting does not appear in list, so cannot be selected

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate, textmatebundles

I tried to load the [Mozaic syntax highlighting](https://patchstorage.com/mozaic-language-support-for-code-text-editors/) into TextMate. While in fact I could create a new Bundle and load the file...

[image]

...it doesn't appear in the list of bundles, so I can't activate it. I tried restarting TextMate, but doesn't help.

Anyone having an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the theme and restarting TextMate* the theme is available through the "View" menu, under "Theme", it is listed as "Monokai-Mozaic".

*: I didn't check for the theme before restarting, this may be optional.

[image: "View" then "Theme" then "Monokai-Mozaic"]

You can also use the "Select Bundle Item" search (`cmd` + `ctrl` + `t`) and select the "other tab" to search through your themes and quickly select them.

[image: The "Select bundle Item" window with a query of "moz" and a selection of "Monokai-Mozaic"]

Comment: Thank you. Sadly it is not applied to the code, it remains Black/White.